# What is the name for a rectangular figure of many sides?

Tags: terminology, polygons

What is a polygon where each edge is at a 90 degree or 270 degree angle to the prior edge (giving both concave and convex vertices) called?  Here is one example of such a shape:

```
----------------------------
|                          |
---                   ------
  |                   |
  |                   |
  |                ----
  |                |
  ------------------
```

What is the mathematical name for these kinds of shapes?  Would it be rectilinear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia these are known as "rectilinear polygons":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon